# DB2 database with circular reference foreign keys

Tags: db2

Can anybody answer what are the issues with DB2 database with circular reference foreign keys. What are the advantage and disadvantage associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

No advantages at all.

The disadvantages are mainly around using the various utilities.
You need to turn of referential integrity before you can restore any of these
tables from a backup copy or reload from a file copy. 
It is very possible that they will then fail the "CHECK" when you try and turn 
the referential integrity on. Once you get into this situation its very difficult
to correct usually involves deleting specific rows and adding them back in again
after the "parent" table is fixed.